# Normal-weight cross-reference to a bold-weight item number

Tags: formatting, hyperref, cross-referencing, enumitem

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}]
    \item One \label{item1}
    \item Two
\end{enumerate}
Link to item \ref{item1}
\end{document}
```

As you can guess, the link in bold. How to make it normal? I have tried

```
Link to item \normalfont{\ref{item1}}
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It worth mentioning that you're using `enumitem` package, then you might look at `ref=〈commands〉` key from **3.1 Label and cross references format** section of the [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

[image]

Therefore, setting up options this way

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}, ref=\arabic*]
```

will produce the desired result

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}, ref=\arabic*]
    \item One \label{item1}
    \item Two
\end{enumerate}
Link to item \ref{item1}
\end{document}
```